# Yii ActiveRecord Primary Key retrieval

Tags: activerecord, yii

I have looked around and have not found anything similar to what I am asking.

Short of extending the CActiveRecord class is there a way to query just the primary key values (or any column's values) of a table and have an array of those values returned instead of a collection of activerecord objects?

ie
ModelName::model()->getColumnValues('column_name');

I keep having to get a list of record that match a certain condition and then run through the results to pull out the column values I need. I would like to cut out the last step and just get the values instead of the entire record.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a CDbCommand you can execute a query and fetch the results from one column with the [queryColumn](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCommand#queryColumn-detail) method. queryColumn returns the results from the first column.

Example:

```
$command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand("SELECT column FROM table WHERE ...");
$result = $command->queryColumn();
```

Comment: I was hoping to do this within the context of active record but this will work nicely. Thank you.

Comment: @DerrickW, if you worry about the ideological purity of using ActiveRecords, then you should do either of two possibilities:

1. do an `array_map` on set of returned records and construct an array of PKs, so you'll stay on the AR abstraction level all the time.
2. or subclass the ActiveRecord to add the method `getColumnValues` you are missing, so this looping logic will stay on the DB abstraction level and your call to retrieve column values will stay on AR abstraction level.